# Jupyter with Redash Dynamic Query

Tags: jupyter, redash

this is my demo of Redash's data.
[image]

and here is my Jupyter demo code:

```
from redash_dynamic_query import RedashDynamicQuery
import pandas as pd
import json
redash = RedashDynamicQuery(
endpoint='http://demo.redash.io/',
apikey='ejsbcH7u2gqCzKjgjltaJhBfrRqkSuTCy1pi5Lur',
#取得したいデータソースIDを設定
data_source_id=1
)

#取得したいクエリIDを設定
query_id = 8174
bind = {
"start_date":  '2017-01-01T00:00:00',
"end_date":  '2019-12-31T23:59:59',
}

#redashのクエリ結果を取得
result = redash.query(query_id, bind)
res = result['query_result']['data']

#jsonを整形
res_format_json = json.dumps(res, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))

print(res_format_json)
```

But i got this error:

```
    ExceptionTraceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-19-6bc390f7a5bf> in <module>
         15 
         16 #redashのクエリ結果を取得
    ---> 17 result = redash.query(query_id, bind)
         18 res = result['query_result']['data']
         19 

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redash_dynamic_query/__init__.py in query(self, query_id, bind, as_csv)
         26 
         27         # post query result
    ---> 28         response = self._api_query_results(self._build_query(query_id, query_body, query_data_source_id))
         29         if 'query_result' in response:
         30             return response

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/redash_dynamic_query/__init__.py in _api_query_results(self, query_string)
         90         )
         91         if response.status_code != 200:
    ---> 92             raise Exception('query_results failed. [%d]' % response.status_code)
         93 
         94         return response.json()

Exception: query_results failed. [404]
```

Am I setting something wrong.
I just did base on origin document of redash_dynamic_query library.
Thank you for reading and please give me a hand if you have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The API key is incorrect because you are using the query API key.
The correct one is the user API key (see edit profile page).